# Location overlay background color is not clear on iOS 5.1

Tags: ios5.1, google-maps-sdk-ios

The Google Maps SDK 1.2.2 on iOS 5.1 location marker does not have a clear background color so it obscures the map underneath it. I have looked into the SDK and have not found a way to gain access to the location marker so I am unable to fix it. Has anyone else had this problem and found a solution?

Screenshot of the location marker obscuring the map on iOS 5.1:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in the simulator. It shouldn't happen on an actual device.

Comment: Same thing happens with 1.9.1 and iOS 8.1. What kind of bug can't be fixed in one and a half year.